# Xamarin Profiler not showing under Analyze tab in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I recently downloaded the Xamarin profiler from here:

https://www.xamarin.com/profiler

and have been attempting to run performance testing for my iOS app.

However according to the Xamarin documents here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/profiler/

I should be able to launch the Xamarin profiler by selecting it under the **Analyze** tab. Unfortunately it does not appear. This post stated they found it under their tools section:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95093/no-option-for-xamarin-profiler-in-visual-studio-2017

but it does not appear their either. From the start menu I can open the Xamarin profiler so I know it is installed properly on my machine. Also I have VS Professional 2017 on my machine as well.

How do I get the Xamarin profiler to appear under the **Analyze** or **Tools** Tab in VS? If not, is their a way I can launch the Xamarin Profiler from the start menu and run performance test for the iOS application?

Comment: Do you have a Enterprise license of VS installed?

Comment: Scratch that I have VS Proffessional. This is why it does not run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this would not work is because I have VS Professional installed not VS Enterprise :(

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Android solution > Select Android Options > Check the Enable developer instrumentation(debugging & profiling)

In Visual Studio Enterprise edition